# Made a simple chess game but its not taking any user input. How do I change that?

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner, user-input

I have made a simple chess game that when the user types an input like a2a4, it moves the piece from a2 to a4.

Here I want user to be able to type any input like b2b4, but the only input it uses is a2a4. It is not using the scanner user input at all. How do I change that?

I have put comments in my code explaining everything. The ones with ******* at the end of comments are the ones im having problems with.Please help, I really need to finish this.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    /* Class Chess
     * with 1 field variable chessBoard
     * Created a 2 d array called board which contains a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h. 
     * These are String arrays which contain the pieces.
     * 
     */
    public class Chess2 {
```

Comment: You're never using `startLetters` or `startNumbers` or `endLetter` or `endNumber`.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but i can't find the main method is this the driver class?

Answer (score 0):

```
             board[1][1] = " ";
              //and put in here. [endLetter][endNumber]
              board[1][3] = temp;
```

Instead of the "1"'s and "3"'s put here your numbers you got from your input just like that:

```
              board[startLetters][startNumbers] = " ";
              //and put in here. [endLetter][endNumber]
              board[endLetter][endNumber] = temp;
```

Did not test it but thats one of the problems u had solved.

edit:

```
              int startLetters = userInput.charAt(0) - 97;
              int startNumbers = userInput.charAt(1) - 48;
              int endLetter = userInput.charAt(2) - 97;
              int endNumber = userInput.charAt(3) - 48;
```

since you are asking for the ascii value of your input you need to lower the value of your number input by 48 (http://www.chip.de/ii/1/2/5/4/9/5/8/0/ascii-93c823e7009f26b0.png).

Comment: Hi. Its not working. Its saying Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 50
 at Chess2.main(Chess2.java:61).  Which is board[startLetters][startNumbers] = " ";   Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found your problem. It's at `int startNumbers = userInput.charAt(1);` and `int endNumber = userInput.charAt(3);`. When you read the number in ASCII you need to decrement by 48 to get the actual number but since the position in arrays is counted from 0 not from 1, you need to decrement by 49 here. example: a2a4 will move the 3rd piece from the bottom up 2 places instead of the 2nd piece.

so just do

```
int startLetters = userInput.charAt(0) - 97;
int startNumbers = userInput.charAt(1)-49;
int endLetter = userInput.charAt(2) - 97;
int endNumber = userInput.charAt(3)-49;
```

Hope this helps!